# delete a substring from a string buffer using Java

Tags: java, stringbuffer

I want to remove a substring from a string buffer every time this substring occures, what I did so far is:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "Alice Bob Alice Bob Alice Bob";
        String substr = "Alice";            
        StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(text);
        strbuf.indexOf(substr);
        strbuf.lastIndexOf(substr);
        while (strbuf != null) {
                strbuf.delete(strbuf.indexOf(substr), strbuf.indexOf(substr) + substr.length());
                System.out.println(strbuf.toString());
            }
}
```

I want to remove every occurrence of "Alice". But it gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
```

I think that the error in the while line.
Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered just using String#replaceAll(String old, String new")? text.replaceAll("Alice", "");

Comment: When will `strbuf` ever be `null`? Your while loop will go forever.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your problem is you are trying to delete a substring that isn't there (after you've removed all the instances of it). You have to change you loop bounds to something like

```
while(strbuf != null && strbuf.indexOf(substr) != -1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because if the `text` does not contains `substr` the `indexOf` returns `-1`, and you call `delete` with `-1`.

Then your loop continues until `strbuf` is `!= null`: **that is forever**.

In your case it throws an exception when you remove all the `substr` occurrences and the next `indexOf` returns `-1`.

Change your loop in this way

```
int i;
while ((i = strbuf.indexOf(substr)) != -1)
    strbuf.delete(i, i + substr.length());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check whether the substring is part of your string

```
int pos = strbuf.indexOf(substr);
if (pos < 0) { // not found...
```

and this will never be false making the loop to be endlesss

```
while (strbuf != null) { ...
```

A better version should be

```
    String text = "Alice Bob Alice Bob Alice Bob";
    String substr = "Alice";            
    StringBuffer strbuf = new StringBuffer(text);
    while (true) {
      int pos = strbuf.indexOf(substr);
      if (pos < 0) break; // ready
      strbuf.delete(pos, pos + substr.length());
      System.out.println(strbuf.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a -1 because the string is no longer found, you need to change the condition to check if you have found the string first, then try and remove it

Answer (score 0):

This is because once you delete the string "Alice" from your stringbuffer, you won't be able to find it again!! So your indexOf() method will return -1 and therefore you will get the java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException